# How long does future.wait() wait for?

Tags: node.js, meteor, error-handling, try-catch, future

I have required npm future package in my meteor application

What can I do if the service providers server does not respond to a http call?

A. How long will future *wait* for the response.

B. (If it does wait forever) how can I stop the *wait* after 4 seconds and repeat the api call 3 more times before returning an error to the user?

Server.js

```
 var requestFunction = function(callback) {
  var f = new future()
  request.post('www.example.com/oauth/request', {
    oauth: {key: 'somekey'},  
      function ResponseFUnction(error, response, body) {    
      if (!err && response.statusCode === 200) {
          var reqBody = querystring.parse(body)
          var responseObj = {
                            oauth_token:reqBody.oauth_token,
                            authenticateUrl: 'www.example.com/oauth/authorize?' + qs.stringify({token: reqBody.oauth_token})
                          }
          return f.return(responseObj)
      }
      else {
        return f.return(error);
      }
    })
  return f.wait()
};

var storeResponseObj = function(data) {
    var store = Meteor.users.update(Meteor.user(), {$set: {'profile.responseFolder': data}})
  return
}


Meteor.methods({
ApiTokens: function() {
try {
      var functionOne =  requestFunction()
      var functionTwo =  storeResponseObj(functionOne)
    } catch (error) { console.log(error) }
    return
  } 
})
```